# How to check space separated inputs in cin to be strictly doubles?

Tags: c++, cin

I have a C++ program that expects a set of positive doubles separated by spaces as input, and then prints them out.

I entered three values separated by 'comma + whitespace's (by mistake), the first number was properly printed, the others were not. How do I check if each value is correct and list all wrong values?

```
cout << "Enter three positive numbers separated by spaces" << endl;
double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
```

> Input: 1 2 3 Output: 1 2 3
>
> Input: 1, 2, 3 Output: 1 0 0

In the second case, I want to detect that there is an error and which terms are not valid doubles and list them:

> Error message: first, second and third are not valid doubles.

If I check for invalid value (0) I would catch 2 and 3, but not 1, since it seems to accept 1.

Update: Code based on the answer below (it still treats first as correct and second as wrong with above input, while first should also be wrong):

```
  cout << "Enter three numbers separated by spaces" << endl;
  double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
  if(cin >> a) 
  {
    cout << "first number was correct" << endl;
    if(cin >> b) 
    {
      cout << "second number was correct" << endl;
      if(cin >> c)
      {
        cout << "third number was correct" << endl;
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "third number was wrong" << endl;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "second number was wrong" << endl;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "first number was wrong" << endl;
  }
```

Comment: "Update: Code based on the answer below" If you're going to do this, leave a comment notifying the person whose answer you're addressing. Its author is unlikely to be sitting refreshing this thread and otherwise can't notice that you've edited the OP unless they happen to be sitting refreshing the index of questions at exactly the right time.

Comment: You cannot input "doubles" into a program. You can only input _numbers_ that may be represented by the `double` data type. I'm not nitpicking: you need to learn and understand the difference between representation and meaning.... and the difference between different categories of representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the state of `cin` to see if any operation failed. If `cin.good()` is true, everything is fine so far.

The easiest way to test an entire input is to just put it in an if-statement

```
if (cin >> a >> b >> c)
   cout << "fine";
else
  cout << "something went wrong";
```

If you want a more fine-grained result, you might want to read one variable at a time, and check the status between each read.

Comment: This way "1 1 1f" will print "fine"

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question based on this approach - it still doesn't work with my example, as the first '1,' is treated as fine (similar to @FrozenHeart comment above).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use boost.

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::vector<std::string> numbers;
split(numbers, input, is_any_of(" \t"), token_compress_on);
for (const std::string& number : numbers)
{
  try
  {
    double value = boost::lexical_cast<double>(number);
    std::cout << number << " is a number" << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const boost::lexical_cast&)
  {
    std::cout << number << " is not a number" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without boost?

Comment: @Anand Of course, but you'll reimplement the wheel then

Answer (score -2):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool validatedCoercion(string input, T &dest) {
    istringstream iss(input);
    if(!(iss >> dest)) return false;
    return iss.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0;
}

vector<string> splitByCommaOrSpace(const string& input) {
    vector<string> result;
    string buffer;
    bool ok = true;
    for(char c : input) {
        if((c == ',' || isspace(c)) && buffer.size() != 0) {
            result.push_back(buffer);
            buffer = "";
        } else {
            buffer += c;
        }
    }
    if(buffer.size() != 0) {
        result.push_back(buffer);
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    double x[N] = {-1};

    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    if(!cin) {
        cerr << "An error occured while reading from stdin." << endl;
    }

    auto doubles = splitByCommaOrSpace(line);
    if(doubles.size() != N) {
        cerr << "Invalid number of input, expected " << N << " got " << doubles.size() << endl;
    }

    int i = 1;
    for(string& s : doubles) {
        if(!validatedCoercion(s, x[i-1])) {
            cout << "column " << i << " is not a valid number.\n";
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;
    for(double d : x) {
        if(x > 0) {
            cout << "number " << i << " is positive.\n";
        } else {
            cout << "number " << i << " is invalid (not strictly positive).\n";
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;
    for(double d : x) {
        cout << "number " << i++ << " is " << x[i-1] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example 1:

```
12.32, 43,2
number was 1 correct.
number was 2 correct.
number was 3 correct.
number 1 is 12.32
number 2 is 43
number 3 is 2
```

Example 2:

```
1.3 23 4
number was 1 correct.
number was 2 correct.
number was 3 correct.
number 1 is 1.3
number 2 is 23
number 3 is 4
```

Example 3:

```
1 2d 3sd
number was 1 correct.
number was 2 wrong.
number was 3 wrong.
number 1 is 1
number 2 is 2
number 3 is 3
```

Example 5:

```
a b
Invalid number of input, expected 3 got 2
number was 1 wrong.
number was 2 wrong.
number 1 is 0
number 2 is 0
number 3 is 0
```

Example 6 (updated code):

```
1 -2 a
column 3 is not a valid number.
number 1 is positive.
number 2 is positive.
number 3 is positive.
number 1 is 1
number 2 is -2
number 3 is 0
```

I think you can go a long way with this.

Comment: @FrozenHeart Edited (compltetly re-wrote)

Comment: Your answer would run as correct with the second input of the question - I want it to error when the inputs are not exactly three double numbers.

Comment: Well, I am not gonna do the whole program for you. All you need is to change this code a little bit. The important parts are the 2 functions `validatedCoercion` and `splitByCommaOrSpace`. The `main` that I gave is just to show how to used them and how they react.

Comment: @Anand I've modified the code a little bit. It now check if each number inputed are positive. Now do what you want with this. (I didn't updated the example 1 through 5.)